# SQL Server Text field casting error and Base64 decoding

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

DP.Docpage is a text field in SQL Server of HTML Documents Base64encoded.

```
VGVzdERhdGE=
is the base64 encoding of text
TextData
```

I used it as a sanity check to see if our Base64 encode in T-SQL was working.

Scenario #1:

```
,CAST(CAST(N'' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary("VGVzdERhdGE=")', 'VARBINARY(MAX)') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) ASCIIEncoding
```

works great everything hard-coded.

Scenario #2:

```
,CAST(CAST(N'' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(DP.DocPage)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) ASCIIEncoding
```

produces the error:

> XQuery [value()]: Cannot explicitly convert from 'xdt:untypedAtomic *' to 'xs:base64Binary'

Scenario #3:

```
,CAST(CAST(N'' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(' + Convert(varbinary,Dp.DocPage) + ')', 'VARBINARY(MAX)') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) ASCIIEncoding
```

produces the error:

> Explicit conversion from data type text to varbinary is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Two issues with the test:

1. You need to use the "[sql:column()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191214.aspx)" function in order to reference a column in the query
2. You are using VARCHAR(MAX) instead of VARBINARY(MAX) as the XML output type of the value() function in the test with the real column.

Regarding the issue of the TEXT datatype field, you can CONVERT that to VARCHAR(MAX) while doing a SELECT * within a derived table, allowing you to reference the converted value from within the XML, given that the sql:column() function requires a string literal field name and won't accept an expression.

The following works (note that the temp tables are for example purposes only, just replace the temp table references with your real tables):

```
-- DROP TABLE #DocPages
-- DROP TABLE #JoinTable
CREATE TABLE #DocPages (DocPageID INT NOT NULL, DocPage [TEXT])
CREATE TABLE #JoinTable (ID INT NOT NULL, DocPageID INT NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO #DocPages (DocPageID, DocPage) VALUES (1, 'VGVzdERhdGE=')
INSERT INTO #DocPages (DocPageID, DocPage) VALUES (23, 'VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Q=')
INSERT INTO #JoinTable (ID, DocPageID) VALUES (768753, 1)
INSERT INTO #JoinTable (ID, DocPageID) VALUES (555, 23)

SELECT  DP.DocPageID,
  CAST(CAST(N'' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("DP.DocPageVarChar"))',
           'VARBINARY(MAX)') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS [ASCIIEncoding]
FROM (SELECT *, CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), doc.DocPage) AS [DocPageVarChar]
      FROM #DocPages doc) DP
INNER JOIN #JoinTable JT
        ON JT.DocPageID = DP.DocPageID
```

Output:

> DocPageID    ASCIIEncoding
>   1            TestData
>   23           This is a test

Comment: Is the SubQuery necessary?
The example you give only pulls one field for example.

I do want to be able to decode that 1 field and also fetch all the others.

Comment: @CharlesMarkCarroll: 1) the sub-query was just to make a usable test since you referenced a table and field but did not provide them. 2) You can select any other fields that you want, but again, you did not mention that in either the text of the question or even imply via sample code. I can update my example to show a temp table with 2 columns if that will help.

Comment: My bad the original query was:

   select 
    
    DP.DocPageID
    ,DP.DocPage   -- this is field I need to decode
    ,D.Createdby_PersID
    ,N.NavURL
    ,N.NavLabel
    ,D.OriginSite_ID
    
    from DocPages DP
    
    inner join Documents D on DP.DocPageId=D.DocId
    
    --inner join Sites S
    --on D.OriginSite_id=S.Site_Code
    
    inner join NavSystems NS on D.OriginSite_ID=NS.OriginSite_ID
    
    inner join Navigation N on NS.NavSysID=N.NavSys_ID

Comment: @CharlesMarkCarroll: I updated the example to pull from a temp table instead of a derived table (not subquery), am showing more than 1 column, and showing more than 1 row.

Comment: Ok I see what you do here, you let the temporary table cast it.

I hate to create a Temporary table just because no cast can cast Text to varchar() but for now I will do it. I hope to find a less hacky way to do it without the temp table, but thanks for working help.

Comment: @CharlesMarkCarroll: Ok, now I see where you mentioned this being a Text datatype. I hadn't noticed that so I just picked VARCHAR. A temp table is by no means required. It was again just an easy way to provide an example that more closely resembles a real table than the derived table I started with.

Comment: @CharlesMarkCarroll: What version of SQL Server are you using? I will find a way to do this with a Text field.

Answer (score 0):

```
Drop Table #UmbracoDocs;
```

select 
    DP.DocPageID As UmbracoDocs_ID
    ,Convert(Varchar(max),DP.DocPage)  AS HtmlPage
    ,D.Createdby_PersID As Person_ID
    ,N.NavURL 
    ,N.NavLabel
    ,D.OriginSite_ID

```
INTO #UmbracoDocs

from DocPages DP

inner join Documents D on DP.DocPageId=D.DocId

inner join NavSystems NS on D.OriginSite_ID=NS.OriginSite_ID

inner join Navigation N on NS.NavSysID=N.NavSys_ID;
```

--select *   from #UmbracoDocs

SELECT 
    UmbracoDocs_ID
    ,HtmlPage
    ,CAST(CAST(N'' AS XML).value('xs:base64Binary(sql:column("#UmbracoDocs.HtmlPage"))', 'VARBINARY(MAX)') AS VARCHAR(MAX)) ASCIIEncoding
    ,Person_ID
    ,NavURL
    ,NavLabel
    ,OriginSite_ID

```
From #UmbracoDocs
```

Comment: Please see my updated answer. This can be handled more elegantly inline via a derived table.